# Existing Account flagged as Duplicate not being added to a duplicate record set

Tags: duplicate-management, duplicate-value, duplicate-matching-rule, findduplicates

I am trying to achieve what I thought was a simple task: create a report displaying all Account records that have been flagged as duplicates.

I created a duplicate rule, a matching rule, made sure both were active and it seems to be working as expected as an account was flagged as a duplicate on the record page.
[image: screenshot of an account with a duplicate]

However, my goal is to report on all Accounts that have been flagged as having a potential duplicate. I thought that when the account is flagged, this automatically created a Duplicate Record Item in the back end. But for all existing accounts that match this newly added/activated rule, there are no DuplicateRecordItem records created.

What am I missing? How can I report on all accounts that are flagged as duplicates with this newly created rule?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As per salesforce [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_management_custom_report_types.htm&type=5), Use duplicate record reports to fine-tune your duplicate and matching rules and share the results of duplicate jobs.

A duplicate records report can include the following records.

- Duplicates created when a rule alerts a user to a possible duplicate,
  but the user creates the duplicate anyway. (To generate this report,
  select the Report option in a duplicate rule.)
- Records manually added to a duplicate record set
- Records in duplicate record sets generated by duplicate jobs

Steps to create:-

1. In Setup, use the Quick Find box to find Report Types.
2. Create a report type, selecting Account, Contact, Lead, or Duplicate
   Record Set as the primary object.If you use person accounts, distinguish them from business accounts
   by adding the Is Person Account field in the field layout properties
   for your report type. If you’re working toward complying with
   various data protection and privacy regulations, consider excluding
   personal data from the report name and description.
3. Click Next.
4. Relate Duplicate Record Items to the primary object that you
   selected. Save the report type.
5. Give your users access to the Duplicate Record Set and Duplicate
   Record Items objects. Then they can create reports based on the
   custom record type you’ve created.

> EXAMPLE Let’s say that you’re using the standard duplicate rule for
> leads. You want to report on the duplicate leads that your rule
> detected. Create a custom report type with Lead as the primary object.
> Then create reports based on that report type.
>
> Or let’s say that you want to share the results of duplicate jobs, or
> see how well your duplicate rules are working overall. Create a custom
> report type with Duplicate Record Sets as the primary object. Then
> create reports based on that report type.

[image]

Comment: So if my edition of Salesforce (enterprise edition) doesn't have duplicate jobs, I can't report on *existing* data that is flagged as a duplicate in the system? Is there any other way to run the duplicate rule on past data?

Comment: I am not sure about reports, but i had used batch job and few custom field to highlight all the duplicates irrespective of duplicates rules in past.

Answer (score 0):

In your duplicate rule settings, you should make sure the Report option is activated for Create or Edit action. Once enabled, when you next create or edit a record that is a duplicate, it will create a DuplicateRecordItem for each possible duplicate with the parent DuplicateRecordSet record.
[image]
Then you can use DuplicateRecordItem records in your report, and group them by Duplicate Record Set Name to show all the potential duplicates for each record.